# How To Add Seconds To Date/Time Format of Prime95 Logging?

Tags: date-time, overclocking, amd-ryzen, threads, prime95

Prime95's default log format is `MMM dd hh:mm` e.g. `Feb 26 07:16`. I am using [Thread Switcher](https://github.com/fhoekstra/thread_switcher) for stability testing which works well switching every 5 seconds. I've had to increase this to 120 seconds in order to identify which cores need more voltage as it's impossible to identify the failed core when leaving it unattended if up to 7 cores are tested inside of a minute (the current granularity of logging in Prime95).

I've looked through the menus but cannot find a way to change Prime95's date/time logging, is there a trick to add seconds (and hopefully milliseconds) to the logging output?

Comment: Did you mean `mmm dd hh:mm`?

Comment: Oops missed out the minutes. It's currently `MMM dd hh:mm` and I need `MMM dd hh:mm:ss` and preferably the milliseconds at the end too.

Comment: If all else fails there is [source code](https://github.com/shafferjohn/Prime95)